# How to insert Latex table into bookdown rmd file

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to insert a latex style table into the rmardown file based on bookdown system. Here is my latex table code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Exact Calculation}\\
\hline
$E(\beta_0)$ & $E(\beta_1)$ & $Var(\beta_0)$ & $Var(\beta_1)$\\
\hline
1.107660 & 1.996823 & 0.0100056979 &  0.0109967641 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

When I copy code above directly into the rmarkdown file, the table cannot be shown.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The table can be shown correctly.

Comment: If I convert it to pdf file, it works. But I want to write it in bookdown file (.Rmd), that fails.

Comment: I don't get your point. rmarkdown files are ASCII files. Do you want your latex codes to be displayed like a table in your .Rmd editor? If so, you must clarify which editor you are using. As far as I know, no editor can render latex table in .Rmd before building the .pdf. Some editors, such as Typora, can render markdown tables. You can convert your latex table into markdown table with pandoc, and paste the markdown table into your .Rmd, and open it with Typora.